# Jetson Orin NX nvidia-container-runtime not utilizing GPU

Tags: kubernetes, nvidia-jetson, cri-o

I'm attempting to get an Nvidia Jetson Orin NX 16gb playing nicely with Kubernetes, using CRI-O.

I've installed the latest stable toolkit on the Jetson.

```bash
NVIDIA Container Runtime version 1.13.5
commit: 6b8589dcb4dead72ab64f14a5912886e6165c079
spec: 1.1.0-rc.2

runc version 1.1.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
spec: 1.0.2-dev
go: go1.18.1
libseccomp: 2.5.1
```

CRI-O is configured with the following

```ini
[crio.runtime]
  default_runtime = "nvidia"

[crio.runtime.runtimes.nvidia]
  runtime_path = "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime"
  runtime_type = "oci"
  runtime_root = "/run/nvidia-container-runtime"
```

The nvidia-device-plugin is installed on the cluster, and has labeled the node accordingly with `nvidia.com/gpu: 1`

The node shows as such

```bash
NAME      STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION       INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
jetson1   Ready    control-plane   7d16h   v1.27.4+k0s   192.168.4.53   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS   5.10.104-tegra   cri-o://1.27.1
```

I've applied a RuntimeClass (though I thought I could do without it if the CRI is defaulting to nvidia)

```yaml
---
apiVersion: node.k8s.io/v1
kind: RuntimeClass
metadata:
  name: gpu-enabled-class
handler: nvidia
```

And this is the Pod that I'm testing

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nvidia-query
spec:
  runtimeClassName: gpu-enabled-class
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
    - name: nvidia-query
      image: dudo/test_cuda
      resources:
        limits:
          nvidia.com/gpu: 1
  tolerations:
    - key: nvidia.com/gpu
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoSchedule
```

This pod is properly scheduled, and executes as intended, running [this script](https://docs.turingpi.com/docs/orin-nxnano-configuring-installing-jetpack-and-other-machine-learning-software-testing#testing), **but it doesn't utilize any gpu** when checking `jtop`.  If I run the script directly on the Jetson, `jtop` shows as expected, and the gpu is utilized, but from the container, nada.

Any ideas on what might be misconfigured? Any recommendations on how to debug this further?